# Removing hashmap key but getting value in previously saved reference

Tags: java, hashmap

I am using Java 1.7

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<Integer, String> testMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    testMap.put(1, "a");
    String testString = testMap.get(1);
    System.out.println("Before remove = " + testString);
    testMap.remove(1);
    System.out.println("After Remove " + testString);
}
```

The output is:

```
Before remove = a
After Remove a
```

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Once you've assigned it, `testString` has a separate reference to the string. It is not linked to the map, and altering the map will not alter `testString`. If you look in the actual map again, you will find `1` has been removed.

Comment: You are printing the previously stored value in `testString` which will be same obviously.

Comment: The variable `testString` is not being changed because it has been set. Your `testString` variable does not reference what's in the `HashMap`, it's a separate object itself.

Comment: Any reference you have saved before `remove` will still reference the same item, even if the map doesn't contain it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in comments, you are printing stored value of `testString`  again.

If you want to see updated value in `testString`   then you have to assign it 
again. like:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> testMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
testMap.put(1, "a");
String testString = testMap.get(1);
System.out.println("Before remove = " + testString);
testMap.remove(1);
testString = testMap.get(1);
System.out.println("After Remove " + testString);
```

Now output will be:

```
Before remove = a
After Remove null
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for quick response. But instead of String i have a customize class then also having the same behavior?

Comment: post your customized class code and what are you trying out there.

Comment: @Nik0990 Yes, same behaviour. Removing something from a map doesn't alter the thing you remove; it only alters the map.

Answer (score 0):

Removing a element from a collection doesn't change the value of the referenced object.
It changes only the map content :

```
 String content = "test";
 testMap.add(1, content);
 testMap.remove(1);
 System.out.println("After Remove " + testMap.get(1)); // "null" is printed
 System.out.println("content"= + content) // content has not changed. So "test" is printed
```